# making text look smooth and clear with custom fonts

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i'm creating a sample application and started to use a custom font. But I noticed that the fonts looks either pixelated or a little funky. Is there a way to make them look smooth?

this is the first attempt:

[image]

this is my second attempt:

[image]

this is the code I'm using to generate the text

```
startButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect.zero)
startButton.setTitle("Get Started", for: .normal)
startButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
startButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "DIN-Regular", size: 20)
startButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 221, green: 94, blue: 13)
//startButton.layer.shouldRasterize = true
startButton.layer.cornerRadius = screenSize.width * 0.015
```

my second attempt was with `shouldRasterize = true`

i appreciate any guidance on where to look for possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change it to `DINNextLTPro`

Comment: i tried that as well. the fonts look different but that weird non smooth looking edges on each letter is just off. Like if the font is being shrunk to a size its not meant for. is there something i'm missing?